# Is it possibile to remove blank value exactly select **ng repeat**

Tags: angularjs

I have a queation to AngularJS Guru. Is it possibile to remove blank value from next listing where klassList is some list of objects. I need 
 **exactly ng-repeat** and not **ng-options** `[{"id":1,"klassName":"11A","pupils":null},{"id":2,"klassName":"12B","pupils":null}]` :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="klassName1"/>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" >
    <option ng-repeat="klass in klassList | filter :  {klassName : klassName1}">{{klass.klassName}}</option>
</select>
```

My target is to obtain dropdown list with possibility of filtering values.

Comment: You should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` here

Comment: what do you have in klassList

Comment: But how would I filter the values ?

Comment: just `[{"id":1,"klassName":"11A","pupils":null},{"id":2,"klassName":"12B","pupils":null}]`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`ng-options`**

```
ng-options="givendata as givendata .klassName for givendata in klassList"
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('SelectorCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.klassList  = [{"id":1,"klassName":"11A","pupils":null},{"id":2,"klassName":"12B","pupils":null}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SelectorCtrl">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedItem" id="state" ng-model="divisionsSource" ng-options="givendata  as givendata.klassName for givendata in klassList">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  
</body>
</html>
```